# Refer to a signal whose name is passed as string (new-style signals/slots)?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, signals-slots

I am refactoring some code that uses old-style signals and slots, and one of the things it does is pass built-in signals as strings (e.g., signalName="clicked()") to another function that actually connects the signals and slots. E.g.:

```
self.connect(widget, QtCore.SIGNAL(signalName), slot)
```

This works fine. The problem is, converting to new-style signals and slots (where the signal is not passed as an argument) makes this more complicated. In new-style signal and slot, the above would be *something* like:

```
widget.[signalName].connect(slot)
```

Where `[signalName]` is something that works. :) I got a lot of things to **not** work without using `eval`:

```
widget.signalName.connect(slot) #AttributeError: widget object has no attribute 'signalName'
```

Based on [a related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python):

```
signalDict={}
signalDict["clicked"]=QtGui.QAbstractButton.clicked
widget.signalDict["clicked"].connect(slot) #AttributeError: widget object has no attribute 'signalDict'
```

Of course there is eval, which actually works:

```
fullCommand="widget." + signalName + ".connect(slot)"
eval(fullCommand)
```

But it uses `eval`, which is sort of frowned-upon. Is there a better way to translate such code into new-style signals and slots, without using `eval`?

Note the original code, that I am trying to translate into new-style signals and slots, is here:
https://github.com/ghosert/VimProject/blob/master/pyqt/book_samples/chap06/imagechanger.pyw

It is from Chapter 6 of Summerfield's book on Qt programming.

Related question:

[Passing Arguments with Newstyle signals in PyQT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807733/passing-arguments-with-newstyle-signals-in-pyqt)

Comment: Use `signalDict["clicked"] = QtGui.QAbstractButton.clicked` instead of `signalDict["clicked"]=QtGui.QAbstractButton.clicked()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
getattr(widget, signalName).connect(slot)
```

You may want to add a `if hasattr(...)` check beforehand to make sure the signal actually exists.

Comment: It works!!! This also helps me appreciate that the dots aren't just for show: new-style connections are truly instance attributes :)

Comment: @neuronet Cool! Also, new-style signals are actually **class** attributes, not instance attributes. If you try to define one as an instance attribute (`self.my_signal = ...`), you'll get an exception. I know because I've tried it before. :)